# Sitecore don't update last run when running a scheduled task

Tags: sitecore, task

I have a couple of scheduled tasks running **every** time the scheduler runs as the Last Run field is never updated by Sitecore. I use Unicorn and can see that Sitecore is actually saving the scheduler item, but without any changes?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?